# Always show div on desktop and toggle on-click on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two DIVs, one is used as button and appear on mobile screens only, and the other one contains information that I want always be visible on desktop and could be toggle on mobile using Show/hide button.

On mobile the information should be hidden initially. The issue is when I hide information on screen below 480px, it is not visible on screen above 480px

Hide the information by clicking Show/hide button then expend the screen you will find noting on screen, I want information be visible in this case.

Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-hide').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.show-hide {
  background-color: #ffa2a2;
  padding: 8px;
  display: none;
}

.information {
  background-color: #a4dca4;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .show-hide {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .information {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-hide">Show/Hide Info</div>

<div class="information">
  Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here,
</div>
```

Comment: Your logic seems to work fine in both variations of screen size, ie. the green div is always visible on larger screens, and hidden on smaller, and toggled by the button. What is the issue you have?

Comment: Hide the information by clicking Show/hide button then expend the screen you will find noting on screen, I want information be visible in this case.

Comment: Ah, I understand your issue. I've added an answer for you below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hide the information by clicking Show/hide button then expend the screen you will find noting on screen, I want information be visible in this case

This behaviour is because the `toggle()` call has added a `style` attribute directly to the element which is difficult to override with CSS, which it needs to be when the media query state changes.

To fix this, use `toggleClass()` instead. You can then ignore this class outside of the media query so the element is always shown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-hide').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('toggle');
  });
});
```

```css
.show-hide {
  background-color: #ffa2a2;
  padding: 8px;
  display: none;
}
.information {
  background-color: #a4dca4;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .show-hide {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .information {
    display: none;
  }
  .information.toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-hide">Show/Hide Info</div>

<div class="information">
  Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here,
</div>
```

You can use this [**example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dve63jfb/) to see the effect working as you resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.show-hide').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
      });
   
  

  $( window ).resize(function() {
    if( $( window ).width()>480){
      $('.information').toggle(true);
    }else{
      $('.information').toggle(false);
    }
    });
    });
```

```css
.show-hide {
      background-color: #ffa2a2;
      padding: 8px;
      display: none;
    }

    .information {
      background-color: #a4dca4;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .show-hide {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .information {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
      .show-hide {
        display: none;
      }
      .information {
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="show-hide">Show/Hide Info</div>

    <div class="information">
      Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here, Some information here,
    </div>
```